# How can I disable YouTube video streaming on VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to disable VLC's feature of playing videos. Can I do that somehow?

I tried doing what's described in the following forum post
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=86323 (moving/renaming the streamout libraries) to no success.

Comment: If removing the libraries doesn't work your only option is the compile with the argument mentioned in the thread. Or use another software.

Comment: Your question is unclear: the title asks to block streaming, the body asks to block playing videos (e.g., .mp4). If you mean *streaming* videos, create a firewall rule blocking VLC.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's what I meant. It seems clear to me given I said youtube video streaming. That's one possibly acceptable alternative. The problem with that is I won't be able to use podcasts.
Also - Why two answers in the comments instead of as proper replies to the question?

Comment: @Unknow0059 Because neither is a proper answer. Mine is just a comment about your link, the other asks for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [to delete or move](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=86323) the .dll files that contain "libstream_out" in one of the folders inside VLC's "plugins" folder.

Alternatively, you can recompile VLC with the `--disable-sout` flag.

Do not use any of the tutorials on VLC's official wiki to compile for Windows (both under Ubuntu or Windows itself), as they are not effective as of 2019 12 - they are deprecated.

If you must use this method, start by finding a thread in the official forums, [such as this one.](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=146175) This worked up until a certain point, but there were roadblocks I could not overcome. Thus, I could not use this method.